# StructureMap 2.5.3 in .Net 4.5.2 Lazy Loading Question

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, structuremap

We are stuck back in StructureMap 2.5.3, running on .Net 4.5.2. I'm writing an app using our Libs that 
needs to startup and login using local data, and not hit the DB.

In our BootStrap StructureMap Calls, we Create a named object for the DB access classes like this

// need one for ADO for JCDC
x.BuildInstancesOf()
.AddInstances( z => z
                .OfConcreteType()
                .WithName( "JCDC" )
                .SetProperty( y => y.ConnectStringName = "SybaseDB" )
                .SetProperty( y => y.TimeOutStringName = "SybaseDBCommandTimeout" )
);

How do I Make this load Lazily?
I know there is  in .net 4 and Func before that, and I've found simple examples
of how to use it, but I haven't wrapped my head around how to get the above code to load lazily

(When structure map inits it , it immediately connect to the DB, which fails offline)

Comment: Take a look on the `Lazy<>`, that might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.5.2

Comment: But you are adding it as an instance `.AddInstances`? What about registering a type instead, then it will be initialized on first request of that type.